Identify Notation, dot (period or point) with semicircle below
I'm not musician, I'm trying to pass a score to MuseScore for my song.

As you can see, I would like to know what is the name for the symbol which is a dot with circular underline (or semicircle below).
Here my score:

And how to place it in my score in MuseScore?

EDIT: Thanks Aaron, I found in Articulations, with View -> Inspector or F8, I changed to Below and changed the duration.
Is it possible to remove the next Silence (8th Silence)?


Hi Jose. Don't change this post, but in the future, please don't add new questions to an existing one. There should only be one question per post, plus it makes existing answers less valuable.

IME it's quite unusual to see a pause below a note (unless e.g. it's part of  a big chord leaving no room above).  It's not strictly wrong, but it would give me, er, pause…

Agreed - if you don't delete it, at least paste it right-side up above the note.

It seems to me that the fermata is below the staff in this case because of the chord symbol (G) above. It'd be a touch crowded up there if the fermata were also above the staff.

It’s called a fermata and can be found on the Breaths and Pauses palette (in MuseScore 4. In MuseScore 3, it's on the Articulations palette.).
To remove a rest from the end of any measure, you can either delete it, change the measure's "Actual Duration" property, or make the rest invisible.

To answer your next question, I believe you can select the note or rest and use ctrl+del (or cmd+del).

Question two: it is not possible to delete rests that make up the full 4 beats of the bar (I’m assuming your score is in 4/4), as if you did it would make the time signature inaccurate. But you could change your final note to a minim.
